# How to improve fetch api JSON download speed or loading icon?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, fetch

As the title reads. How do I improve my fetch api JSON download speed specfically for the comments.

Trying to keep the Javascript to ES6.

When you click a "post" it will run the getSelectedPost and GetComments function. Why is fetching the comments JSON file so slow? Is this because it is just a large file?

Anything I can add to improve performance and/or a potential loading icon?

Thanks

```js
getPosts();

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.matches('.post') || event.target.parentElement.matches('.post')) {
      const postId = event.target.getAttribute('data-postid') || event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-postid');  
      getSelectedPost(postId);
      getComments(postId);
    }
})

function getPosts(){
    const posts = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    fetch(posts)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
      for (const post of data){

        const markup = `
          <div class="post" data-postid="${post.id}">
            <span class="title">${post.title}</span>
            <p>${post.body}</p>
          </div>
        `;
        
        document.getElementById('back').style.display = 'none';
        const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
        grid.innerHTML += "";
        grid.innerHTML += markup;
      }
    })
      .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    })
}

function getSelectedPost(postId){  
    const postSingle = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + postId;
    
    fetch(postSingle)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {

        const markup = `
          <div class="post active" data-postid="${data.id}">
            <span class="title">${data.title}</span>
            <p>${data.body}</p>
          </div>
        `;
        
        document.getElementById('back').style.display = 'block';
        const single = document.querySelector('.single');
        const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
        grid.innerHTML = "";
        single.innerHTML = "";
        single.innerHTML = markup;
    })
      .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    })
}

function getComments(postId){
    const postComments = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + postId + "/comments";
    console.log(postComments)
    
    fetch(postComments)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        for (const comment of data){

          const markup = `
          <div class="comment" data-commentid="${comment.id}">
          <span class="name">${comment.name}</span>
          <a href="${comment.email}" class="email">${comment.email}</a>
          <p>${comment.body}</p>
          </div>
          `;

          const comments = document.querySelector('.comments');
          comments.innerHTML += "";
          comments.innerHTML += markup;
        }
    })
      .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    })
}

document.getElementById('back').addEventListener('click', getPosts);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: roboto;
}

#back {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
    max-width: 78.75rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.post {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.post:hover, .post.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post.active {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.post.active:hover {
  cursor: default;
}

.title, .name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button id="back">Back</button>
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div class="single"></div>
    <div class="comments"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try anything to improve the performance. You are saying that comments are large files. Why not to load only few comments which will actually show on the webpage and then load rest of it on scroll or similar events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of things you have to refactor it is using `innerHTML`, in the code below, i just used it once.

```js
getPosts();

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.matches('.post') || event.target.parentElement.matches('.post')) {
      const postId = event.target.getAttribute('data-postid') || event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-postid');  
      getSelectedPost(postId);
      getComments(postId);
    }
})

function getPosts(){
    const posts = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    fetch(posts)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
      let grid = '';
      for (const post of data){

        const markup = `
          <div class="post" data-postid="${post.id}">
            <span class="title">${post.title}</span>
            <p>${post.body}</p>
          </div>
        `;
        
        document.getElementById('back').style.display = 'none';
        grid += markup; 
      }
      return grid;
    }).then((grid) => {
      document.querySelector('.grid').innerHTML = grid;
    })
      .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    })
}

function getSelectedPost(postId){  
    const postSingle = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + postId;
    
    fetch(postSingle)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {

        const markup = `
          <div class="post active" data-postid="${data.id}">
            <span class="title">${data.title}</span>
            <p>${data.body}</p>
          </div>
        `;
        
        document.getElementById('back').style.display = 'block';
        const single = document.querySelector('.single');
        const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
        grid.innerHTML = "";
        single.innerHTML = "";
        single.innerHTML = markup;
    })
      .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    })
}

function getComments(postId){
    const postComments = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + postId + "/comments";
    console.log(postComments)
    
    fetch(postComments)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
      let comments = '';
        for (const comment of data){

          const markup = `
          <div class="comment" data-commentid="${comment.id}">
          <span class="name">${comment.name}</span>
          <a href="${comment.email}" class="email">${comment.email}</a>
          <p>${comment.body}</p>
          </div>
          `;

          
          comments += markup;
        }
      return comments;
    }).then((comments) => {
      document.querySelector('.comments').innerHTML = comments;
    })
      .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    })
}

document.getElementById('back').addEventListener('click', getPosts);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: roboto;
}

#back {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
    max-width: 78.75rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.post {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.post:hover, .post.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post.active {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.post.active:hover {
  cursor: default;
}

.title, .name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button id="back">Back</button>
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div class="single"></div>
    <div class="comments"></div>
</div>
```